# Comparação entre campos mysql

Tags: mysql

Tenho uma tabela Mysql onde armazeno os anos que pego de um cadastro, porém estou criando uma busca onde o usuário seleciona de uma data a outra. No Mysql fiz dessa forma:

```
SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE AnoEmpresa BETWEEN 1970 and 2014;
```

Só que não retorna nada, mesmo tendo dados dentro dessas datas.

Comment: Qual é o tipo da coluna `AnoEmpresa`?

Comment: CHAR...nem me toquei nisso. Se eu converter para YEAR, será que perco as informações cadastradas?

Comment: Converti de CHAR para YEAR e funcionou... obrigado!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A tua query parece correta.

A unica coisa que imagino é teres a coluna `AnoEmpresa` num formato não numérico. Nesse caso o MySQL vai estar à procura de uma string. (provavelmente com o tamanho entre 1970 e 2014 caracteres). Tenta mudar para um tipo numérico ou data: `TINYINT`, `YEAR` ou `DATE`...

Comment: Obrigado Sérgio...deu certo...